# Unhandled Continue Record followining class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.TabIdRecord

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When opening xls it 'This workbook has lost its VBA project, ActiveX controls, and any other features that are related to the program.tips',and then the program in

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
// Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
```

> throw the org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException.
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException: Unhandled Continue
>   Record followining class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.TabIdRecord   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.readNextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.nextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:251)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:327)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:308)

But save as new xls,it worked.I confused.If you have good advice, please share with me.Thanks.

Comment: Reasons of this error are `*.xls` workbooks which are *not* proper workbooks at all. For example: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57952 -> The provided `error.xls` contains a hidden sheet named "antrFaT" which is not a properly formatted `Excel` worksheet. And https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50967 -> The provided `ISBN_UPD_PL_20100104_1525.xls` even cannot be opened without errors using `Excel` itself. So I suspect also your workbook will be such a not proper  `*.xls` workbook created by some third party software which does something wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.I prefer your point of view.This is in the windows10 environment but the *.xls is copied from the MacBook and it does have some errors. I'm still trying to solve the problem with the program now.